# How to move Ubuntu on Windows to Drive D or other drive?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Currently [Ubuntu running on Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL) can only be installed in C drive of Windows. Other applications can be moved to Drive D or other drive. When trying to move the installed Ubuntu on Windows, it throws this message:

[image]

Is there a way to move Ubuntu to other drive?

Comment: What you want isn’t possible at this time

Answer (score 13):

**Disclaimer:** Moving Windows Store Apps is not directly supported. The following steps are like workaround. This only works with WSL distribution packages and not for all Windows Store packages. As the question asked with using Ubuntu 18.04, the paths are related to that specific version. But this method works mostly every distribution installed in WSL.

### If distribution is not installed:

- Run this command in Powershell which opens the install location of that Windows Store package.

```
Explorer.exe (Get-AppxPackage *Ubuntu*).InstallLocation
```

Replace Ubuntu with your installed distribution name. For Ubuntu 18.04 the folder path is:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
```

- Copy the `install.tar.gz` and `ubuntu1804.exe` (or other name) where you want to install.
- Run `ubuntu1804.exe` which will install the distribution. This may take some time. After successful installation, there will be a `rootfs` and `temp` folder.

### If distribution is installed:

This method only works in Windows 10 [Build 18305 or above](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-18305).

- Close any running instances of that WSL distribution.
- List the installed distribution to get distribution name:

```
wsl.exe --list --all
```

- Export the required distribution to a tar.gz file:

```
wsl.exe --export Ubuntu-18.04 D:\MyFolder\MyFile.tar.gz
```

- Import that same file but with **different path and different name**:

```
wsl.exe --import MyDistro D:\MyFolder D:\MyFolder\MyFile.tar.gz
```

- Launch the distribution:

```
wsl.exe --distribution MyDistro
```

Comment: The fresh install version worked for me, but I had to copy all of the files from the `CanonicalGroupLimited` folder to where I wanted to install the distro. Got an error otherwize.

Comment: before the import step, you should do this wsl --unregister Ubuntu. That way you can import it with the same distro name instead of creating another one.